# Sending JSON jQuery Ajax to PHP and back

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm having problems sending a JSON jQuery array via Ajax to a PHP script. What is the problem here:

```
var tee = $('#voting_image img').attr('id');
var vote = 1;
var thing = {tee: tee, vote: vote};
var encoded = $.toJSON(thing);

$.ajax({
    url:             '/vote_save.php',
    type:            'POST',
    dataType:        'json',
    data:            'vote='+encoded,
    success: function(data)
    {
        var back = $.evalJSON(data).name;
        $('#voting_hint_name').html(back);
        $('#voting_buttons').html('<div id="voting_buttons"><a href="#" id="vote_yes">PRINT IT</a><a href="#" id="vote_no">DON\'T PRINT IT</a></div>');
    },
    error:function ()
    {
        $('#voting_buttons').html('<div id="voting_buttons"><a href="#" id="vote_yes">PRINT IT</a><a href="#" id="vote_no">DON\'T PRINT IT</a></div>');
        alert("There was a problem, your vote was not saved, please try again!");
    }
});
```

This is the PHP

```
if (isset($_POST['vote'])&&isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    $tee_data = json_decode($_POST['vote']);
    $the_tee = $tee_data['tee'];
    $responce = array('name'=> 'Alex Wow', 'test'=> '1');
    echo json_encode($responce);
}
else {
    echo "error";
}
```

The error I am getting in [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug) is:

> Error: JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no `$.toJSON` method in jQuery, you are probably looking for [`$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) and by the way you are already creating JSON here:

```
var thing = {tee: tee, vote: vote};
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention I'm using a json plugin for jQuery

Comment: @Alex Crooks - What plugin would that be?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

but I am only using it in the example as I'm struggling to get this to work so trying different things

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you send data as object, try to send as array
`var thing = {tee: tee, vote: vote};` to array

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question: [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

The accepted answer links to a JSON serialization plug-in recommended by John Resig (the creator of jQuery).  It doesn't really address your specific bug, but perhaps using that plug-in will help you arrive at a stable solution.

From looking at it briefly, if you use that plug-in, it appears you would then replace this line:

```
var encoded = $.toJSON(thing);
```

with this:

```
var encoded = JSON.stringify(thing);
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responces, I went with:

```
$.getJSON(
            '/vote_save.php?vote='+encoded,
            function(data) 
            {
                $('#voting_hint_name').html(data.bob);
                $('#voting_buttons').html('<div id="voting_buttons"><a href="#" id="vote_yes">PRINT IT</a><a href="#" id="vote_no">DON\'T PRINT IT</a></div>');
            }   
    );
```

instead of $.ajax and it worked.