# Sending javascript class object to php

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending JSON jQuery Ajax to PHP and back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462409/sending-json-jquery-ajax-to-php-and-back)

i need to send the following object to a php file i tried it through json stringify but could not do it .i dont want to change the format in which these attributes are already defined and also is json the only way to send such objects? i wand to do something like this

```
function contact()
{
contact.menu=null;
contact.access=null;
contact.state=null;
}
$.post("myfile.php",{contact:contact},function(data){alert(data);});
///php code
$contact= $_POST['contact'];
echo $contact['menu'];
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**JavaScript:**

```
var contact = {
    menu: null,
    access: null,
    state: null
};
$.post("myfile.php", {contact: contact}, function(data) { 
    alert(data);
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
echo $contact['menu'];
```

**UPDATE:**

Answer to your question in comments:

```
var contact = {
    menu: null,
    state:  null,
    access: null,
    fill: function() {
        this.menu = 1; // $("div#sm").html(); 
        this.state = 2;
        this.access = 3;
    }
};

contact.fill();

$.post("myfile.php", {contact: contact}, function(data) { 
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: i am changing the class attributes down the code like contact.menu=$("div#sm").innerhtml();so i dont want to change the format . can i do contact['menu']=$("div#sm").innerhtml(); using your code ?instead .
ill try that right now!

Comment: Check the update of my answer. Also there's a jQuery method `$.html()`, not `innerhtml`, as you're writing.

Comment: that innerhtml was just to tell you want i wanted and thanks for the answer .also figured that now anywhere in the code i can do contact['menu']=$("div#sm").html();

Comment: in php when im only getting the first index of the contact only menu and not 
echo $contact['access'];

Comment: Yea, you can initialize object's property later. `var contact = {};` then: `contact.menu = $("div#sm").html();` or `contact['menu'] = $('div#sm');`

Answer (score 0):

Object contact is supposed to be like this

```
 var contact = {
    menu :null,
    access:null,
    state:null
   }
```